# Complex MYSQL select

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have different tables in my MYSQL database and I need to create a SELECT query that will check certain values before selecting a row.

It's basically 3 tables (news, tags and news_tags).

1. news contains information about a news.
2. tags information about tags.
3. news_tags store which tag is used by a news.

Here are my 3 different tables (simplified of course)

To illustrate:

**news:**

```
id | status
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 0
```

**tags:**

```
tag_id | tag_name
1      | name 1 
2      | name 2
```

**news_tags:**

```
id | news_id | tag_id
1  | 1       | 1
2  | 1       | 2
3  | 2       | 1
4  | 3       | 1
5  | 3       | 2
```

Now, at first I wanted to know how many times each tag was being used.
So I came up with this query

```
SELECT tags.tag_name, news_tags.tag_id, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM news_tags 
LEFT JOIN tags 
ON tags.tag_id = news_tags.tag_id 
GROUP BY news_tags.tag_id 
ORDER BY count DESC
```

This give me the following output

```
tag_name | count
name 1   | 3 
name 2   | 2
```

Now my problem is that I don't want to count those that the `news.status = 0`;
So if we look at my example, in the `news` table the row with the `id = 3` has a `status = 0`.
The `count` should not take in effect where `news_id = 3` in the `news_tags` table.

Basically the desired output should be

```
tag_name | count
name 1   | 2 
name 2   | 1
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you please provide the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join it with `news` table so you can query for `status`

```
SELECT tags.tag_name, news_tags.tag_id, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM    news_tags 
        LEFT JOIN tags 
            ON tags.tag_id = news_tags.tag_id 
        LEFT JOIN news
            ON news.id = news_tags.news_id
WHERE   news.status = 1
GROUP BY news_tags.tag_id 
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: FWIW: it should be news.status = 1